# how to get dinamically generated input fields vaues with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html form that has some input fields generated on a button click after the page is loaded. All inputs are wraped by tags.
The input that is generated on button click looks like this:

```
<div class="row t-a t-line" id="1">
  <div class="col-md-1">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cod[]">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="piesa[]">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
   <input class="form-control cantitate" type="number" name="cantitate[]" value="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

The next one will have id 2 and so on. I use jquery serialize

```
var form = $( this ).serialize();
```

But when i log in the console the var form, all the values are there except the dinamically generated input fields.
Any ideas?

Thank in advance!

update: 
Yes, the form is wraped raound all input fields

the js code:

```
$( document ).on( "submit","form", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
       var form = $( this ).serialize();
        form += '&action=update&id=<?php echo $id; ?>';
        form += '&serie-produs='+$('#serie-produs').val();
        form += '&Total='+$('#total-cu-TVA').val();
        form += '&TotalFT='+totalFT.toFixed(2);
        form += '&TotalT='+totalT.toFixed(2);

        console.log(form);
        var action = "assets/tickete-controller.php";       
        $.post(action, form, function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //$('.rezultat-filtre').html(data.produsItems);         
                if(data.type == "success"){
                    $("#message").removeClass('alert-danger');
                    $("#message").css('display', 'block');
                    $("#message").addClass('alert-success');
                    $('#rsponse-message').html(data.message);                   
                    $("#message").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
                    var link = data.linkPdf;
                    console.log(link);
                    window.open(link, '_blank');                    
                }               
            },'json');
    });
```

Comment: are these inputs added inside your form?

Comment: Can you share your JS code too?

Comment: When are you declaring `var form = $( this ).serialize();` ? is it at the begginning of `$(document).ready()` ? Maybe you should update the form variable when you add new input elements

Comment: What you're describing doesn't happen, which means there must be something else affecting it.  See here... http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/px9bhnyg/

Comment: thanks for your response. But your fiddle shows an example where the form exists fom the begining.

Answer (score -2):

This is because

```
var form = $( this ).serialize();
```

Takes all values from elements that were in the DOM initially. In other words, you are getting those elements' values by using "READY" event only on HTML objects that were loaded at the beginning.
To get the values from the elements added dynamically you will have to add an event listener for them:

E.g.

```
$(document).on(<event_type>, <element_ID_or_other_selector>, function() {
...
<your_implementation>
});
```

This way you will be able to get their values on a specified event.

Another way to get their values is by using

```
$('#your_element_ID').val();
```

for each dynamic element

Comment: `.serialize()` will serialize the form in its state at that point in time - it doesn't care when inputs were added to it, or how they were added to it.  As long as they have a `name` attribute then they will be included in the serialization.

Comment: this was also my opinion but still, the dinamic inputs are not serialized.